# Changing element in a 2D list changes elements in whole column

Tags: python-3.x, multidimensional-array

I recently took part in a competitive programming contest but got stuck on a question. The question is Ada King.
[Link for the problem]
[1]: https://www.codechef.com/JULY20B/problems/ADAKING

My approach to the problem was that if we leave a k number of empty squares for the king on the board starting from the top and then fill the remaining with obstacles, then the king can only move k cells. The logic turned out to be right, but in the code I wrote, I had trouble changing the first square of the first row to contain 'O' representing the king, the program instead sometimes changed all elements of the first column to 'O' or the first two. The same story with '.' used to represent empty squares. Can someone please look at my code and suggest any corrections

```
x=['X' for __ in range(8)]
dot=['.' for ___ in range(8)]
t=int(input())
for _ in range(t):
    arr=[]
    for i in range(8):
        arr+=[x]
    k=int(input())
    row=k//8
    extra=k%8
    for i in range(row):
        arr[i]=dot
    for j in range(extra):
        arr[row][j]='.'
    arr[0][0]='O'
    for i in arr:
        print(*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into problems with [list mutability](https://pybit.es/immutable-types.html). A way to fix your problem is to make copies of the lists with `[:]`. So replace these 2 lines with `arr+=[x[:]]` and `arr[i]=dot[:]`.